# How to select a specific value of an attribute from a series of values using XQuery?

Tags: xquery

How do I select a specific attribute value from a series of values using XQuery?

My XML file looks like this:

```
<unit id="01" xref="entry01 entry02">
```

How do I select a specific value -- such as entry01 --- from the **xref** attribute and assign it to a variable?

I need to select the individual values from the attribute **xref**, because additional features for these values are defined later in the file:

```
<features xref="entry01" font-size="2">
<features xref="entry02" font-size="3">
```

I would like to organize the entries into a table such as one exemplified below. The columns defined by the attributes as follows: unit id, xref, font-size.

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>01</td>
<td>entry01</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>01</td>
<td>entry02</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `fn:tokenize` to split at space (or all whitespace) characters, depending on you needs:

Split at a single space:

```
tokenize(<unit id="01" xref="entry01 entry02"/>/@xref, " ")[1]
```

Allow multiple spaces directly following each other:

```
tokenize(<unit id="01" xref="entry01  entry02"/>/@xref, " +")[2
```

Split at a single whitespace (I changed the attribute value to contain a tab character):

```
tokenize(<unit id="01" xref="entry01    entry02"/>/@xref, "\s")[2]
```

Comment: I've amended the example, because some of the original question did not show up properly.

I also have trouble using tokenize with a variable, which I use to pick up the <unit> entries from the XML file: for $units in doc("units.xml")/units

Comment: @ritzdiamond, The XML document you have provided doesn't contain any element named `units`. Your comment above contradicts this fact. It is recommended that you update the question with the *real* XML document, or *accept* this answer (click on the check-mark next to the answer) and ask a new question.